# Error in plane transformation

Tags: rotation, geometry, transformation

I have a bunch of coplanar points, who sit on plane `P`. I want to translate the plane to `Q` with the points upon. Here is what I do:

I take three points from `P`, say `a`, `b`, `c`. Their centroid is denoted by `c(a,b,c)`.

I pick the local origin as `O = c(a,b,c)` and local `XYZ` as:

```
x = normalize(Oa);
v = normalize(Ob);
z = x.crossProduct(v);
y = x.crossProduct(z);
```

I apply the same method to their global coordinates on `Q`, which are `d`, `e`, `f`.

```
O_ = c(d,e,f);
x_ = normalize(Od);
v_ = normalize(Oe);
z_ = x_.crossProduct(v_);
y_ = x_.crossproduct(z_);
```

Then, I use the transformation matrix as follows:

```
Matrix input = [x,y,z];
Matrix output = [x_,y_,z_];
Matrix T = output.multiply(input.transpose());
```

After this step, I multiply the coordinates of a point `p` that sit in plane `P` with matrix `T`. Of course, before that, I take the vector difference `p - O`.
The result should be the transformed point minus target origin (`q - O_`).

Hence, for each `p` in `P`, I transform `p` to its place in `Q`, which is denoted by `q` using the following computation:

```
q = T.multiply(p.subtract(O)).add(O_);
```

But what I get is, the reflection of the points through an imaginary (I don't know which) axis.

Am I missing some step? Is there a wrong computation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a typo in your question or the actual mistake:

```
x = normalize(Oa);
v = normalize(Ob);
z = a.crossProduct(b);
y = x.crossProduct(z);
```

For one you don't seem to be using `v` at all, but your `z` looks wrong to me. Did you mean the following?

```
z = normalize(Oa.crossProduct(Ob));
```

Note the `Oa` and `Ob` instead of `a` and `b`. The difference is the preserved perpendicularity of z on the plane `P` if `P` is moved away from the origin. I guess you wanted to do that through `p.subtract(O)` but that doesn't suffice.

Also note that I normalized `z`. This will result in orthonormal XYZ on both planes `P` and `Q` and means that scale is preserved. If the triangles `abc` and `def` are not similar (i.e. one is stretched) then `T(P) = Q` but `T(a) != d`. Don't normalize anything if you want to preserve stretching.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I corrected it. You suggest that I don't normalize the vector don't you?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. `T(P) = Q` only, or that and `T(abc) = def`.